# Four Places for Notary Public on Form

Tags: power-of-attorney, notaries

I am looking at Power of Attorney form here, (opened in Chrome) http://www.citibank.com/us/geb/resources/pdf/Power_of_Attorney_NY.pdf

On page 4, there are four spaces for Notary Public to sign.

What law says there must be 4 Notary Publics on a Power of Attorney form?

[image]

Comment: Your link brings you to a log-in page instead of the referenced PDF.

Comment: @RonBeyer I opened in Chrome and attached screenshot.

Answer (score 2):

Since all 4 notarization certificates are identical, this is probably to allow for the notary or notaries to take acknowledgements for 4 different people. Looking at a few NY POA forms on the web, it appears normal in NY for the principal, the agent, any secondary agents, and any successor agents, to all sign and have their acknowledgements taken by a notary. Each of these people could be in different places and sign on different days. The 4 different certificates would allow for that.

When notaries looks at this, each notary will be considering whether the wording is acceptable for the state in which the notary and signer are located. The notaries will also be considering whether their states require a seal or stamp; it would be hard to fit a seal or stamp on the form shown in the question. If some of the notaries are not satisfied with the preprinted certificates each will attach a certificate that conforms with the law of the notary's state.

Comment: OK, so in my case one parent wants to give me power of attorney. Do we need two notaries, one for my parent, and one for me. Kindly clarify.

Comment: You need as many notaries as there are events of signing. If you can do it at the same time in the same room, one is enough.

Comment: I agree with @user6726